# Update a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to change the columns of tables that are of type CHAR to VARCHAR2, but they have asked me to do it automatically because they are 100 tables. One way to update all the columns of a table in Oracle without the need to put column by column is with a for extracting columns from the view of user_tables, but these tables have data when doing the data change the white spaces that CHAR handles to the right are also passed to VARCHAR2 what I need is to update the data of the table applying an RTRIM , I did it with an update table set column = rtrim (column); but they ask me that the update is not column by column but in the whole table so that it is only a query, is there a way to achieve it? I have googled and only find the syntax that I already use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL to generate the neccessary statements. A minimal example:

```
CREATE TABLE t0 (i INT);
CREATE TABLE t1 (a CHAR(10), b NUMBER, c VARCHAR2(30), d CHAR(40));
INSERT INTO  t1 VALUES('a',1,'a','a');
CREATE TABLE t2 (x CHAR(10), y CHAR(20 CHAR), z CHAR(30 BYTE));
INSERT INTO  t2 VALUES('b','b','b');

SELECT 'UPDATE ' || table_name ||' SET ' || 
       LISTAGG(column_name||'=RTRIM('||column_name||')', ', ')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) || '; COMMIT;' as sql
  FROM user_tab_columns
 WHERE data_type='CHAR'
 GROUP BY table_name
 ORDER BY table_name;
```

Will produce the following statements:

```
UPDATE T1 SET A=RTRIM(A), D=RTRIM(D); COMMIT;
UPDATE T2 SET X=RTRIM(X), Y=RTRIM(Y), Z=RTRIM(Z); COMMIT;
```

Likewise,

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' MODIFY ('||LISTAGG(
        column_name||
      ' VARCHAR2('||data_length||' '||DECODE(char_used,'B','BYTE','C','CHAR')||')', ', ') 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) ||');' as sql
  FROM user_tab_columns
 WHERE data_type='CHAR'
 GROUP BY table_name
 ORDER BY table_name;
```

will produce

```
ALTER TABLE T1 MODIFY (A VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), D VARCHAR2(40 BYTE));
ALTER TABLE T2 MODIFY (X VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), Y VARCHAR2(80 CHAR), Z VARCHAR2(30 BYTE));
```

Please test your script thoroughly, get somebody else to look over the script and back up the database before running it.

EDIT:

You could wrap the statments in a PL/SQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p AS
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
     SELECT 'UPDATE ' || table_name ||' SET ' || 
            LISTAGG(column_name||'=RTRIM('||column_name||')', ', ')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) as stmt
       FROM user_tab_columns
      WHERE data_type='CHAR'
      GROUP BY table_name
      ORDER BY table_name)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.stmt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE r.stmt;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;

  FOR r IN (
     SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' MODIFY ('||LISTAGG(
             column_name||
           ' VARCHAR2('||data_length||' '||DECODE(char_used,'B','BYTE','C','CHAR')||')', ', ') 
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) ||')' as stmt
       FROM user_tab_columns
      WHERE data_type='CHAR'
      GROUP BY table_name
     ORDER BY table_name)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.stmt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE r.stmt;
  END LOOP;
END p;
/
```

EDIT:

EDIT:

Oh, I forgot, you might want to reorganize the tables to make the freed up white space available again. A minimal example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (c CHAR(2000));
CREATE INDEX i ON t(c);
INSERT INTO t SELECT 'x' FROM all_objects;
67,114 rows inserted.
```

The table is 184 MB, the index 240 MB:

```
SELECT segment_type, segment_name, round(bytes/1024/1024) AS mb 
  FROM user_segments WHERE segment_name IN ('T','I');

INDEX I 240
TABLE T 184
```

Now, if you convert and rtrim the table, the table and index are still the same size:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY (c VARCHAR2(2000));
UPDATE t SET c = RTRIM(c);

INDEX I 240
TABLE T 184
```

Only after you reorganize the table, Oracle gets rid of the spaces which are not needed any more. The table is now 1 MB, the index 2 MB:

```
ALTER TABLE t MOVE;
ALTER INDEX I REBUILD;

INDEX I 2
TABLE T 1
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer has been very helpful to me, will you know if I can use executing this inside a PL / SQL?

Comment: Sure. Personally, I wouldn't feel comfortable with it, I'd rather generate a SQL script with the statements, which I'd get double checked and tested in a test database. But for sake of the example, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Do you mention "want to rearrange the tables so that the freed white space is available again" in what way is this accomplished?